# how to install subversion 1.7 to mac os?

Tags: macos, svn, operating-system

I have installed svn 1.8 in my mac os.Now I need to use svn 1.7 sometimes. How to install svn 1.7 without removing 1.8? I had tried to find subversion 1.7. It's really a difficult job.Why is there not a installable svn1.7 1.8 etc for mac os?

Comment: Follow the documentation on the site?

Comment: I had "follow" it many times. None of links in the page is usable.In the page:http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html. In the osx section,could not find the 1.7 version in the links.Svn 1.8 not compatable with 1.7. And intall subversion is a so hard job. I dont know why subversion is still popular.

Comment: **Now I need to use svn 1.7 sometimes** -- *Why?*

Comment: Some repositories i needed to use support only svn 1.7 and they are served by a customized svn server which dot not support other svn version.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Just upgraded to Yosemite and now SVN is complaining. Rechecked-out the branch, still complaining. Updated everything I could (Dev tools, xcode) on my MBP, still complaining.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did anyone tried this?
http://www.smartsvn.com/subversion/download#osx

"Client Only" version worked for me.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: Yes, maybe they've completely stopped supporting older versions. Did you try download link at the top?